# Integrating Laravel 5.2.* with firebase (Already tried j42)

Tags: php, json, firebase, laravel-5

I am facing the errors while using J42,

This is the composer.json I am using for the require element

```
"php": ">=5.5.9",
"laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
"laravelcollective/html": "^5.2"
```

I need to add firebase to my application, it is really important .
If anyone can provide me with the step by step installation along with an example it would be really great.

I have tried all sorts of possibilites

```
'Firebase' => J42\LaravelFirebase\LaravelFirebaseFacade::class

  //  `'Firebase' => J42\LaravelFirebase\LaravelFirebaseFacade
```

**::class**

even adding this class also seems an error since J42/laravel-firebase haven't mentioned it but nothing works without it.
I have already added J42/Laravel... to my composer.json but it also don't work, shows error App/Http/Controller/Firebase class not found
So if anyone could please help me in this issue, then it would be really great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line to your composer.json and run composer update:

```
{
   "require": {
   "j42/laravel-firebase": "dev-master"
   }
}
```

Then add the service providers and facades to config/app.php

```
  'J42\LaravelFirebase\LaravelFirebaseServiceProvider',

  'Firebase'        => 'J42\LaravelFirebase\LaravelFirebaseFacade'
```

Finally, you should configure your firebase connection in the config/database.php array.

Simple Access Token

```
'firebase' => array(
'host'      => 'https://<you>.firebaseio.com/',
'token'     => '<yoursecret>',
'timeout'   => 10,
'sync'      => false,           // OPTIONAL: auto-sync all Eloquent models with Firebase?
```

)

Comment: if you are looking for firebase authentication in laravel then you can use this package https://github.com/vinkas0/firebase-auth-laravel Its supports latest 5.2